# javascript学習方法について

Tags: javascript

HTMLやCSSの理解はしていますが、このままJSの勉強もしていこうと思っています。
独学で勉強された方に質問です。
どのくらいの勉強を、どうやって勉強されましたか？
どこから手をつければいいのか迷っている状態です。

Comment: http://dotinstall.com/ こちらでも見て勉強してください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

今は無料で使えるオンラインの学習サイトがいろいろあるので、その辺りから手をつけてみてはいかがでしょうか？

とりあえずいくつかリンクを貼っておきます。

[初心者でもほぼ無料でJavaScriptを勉強できるコンテンツ17選](http://paiza.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/03/03/%E5%88%9D%E5%BF%83%E8%80%85%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%BB%E3%81%BC%E7%84%A1%E6%96%99%E3%81%A7JavaScript%E3%82%92%E5%8B%89%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%8417)
[Javascript.com](https://www.javascript.com/)
[Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/free)
[Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript)